# Update column1 case Date between @Date1 AND @Date2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update one column from condition of date which is another column.

```
DECLARE @FIRSTDATE DATE ='2016-11-01';
DECLARE @LASTDATE DATE ='2016-11-30';

UPDATE A 
SET A.Status = CASE 
                  WHEN B.Date IS NULL THEN 0
                  ELSE 1 
               END,
    A.DESCRIPTION = CASE  
                       WHEN B.Date IS NULL 
                          THEN 'UNPAID'
                       WHEN B.Date BETWEEN @FIRSTDATE AND @LASTDATE  
                          THEN 'CARRY FORWORD'
                       ELSE 
                          'PAID'   
                     END
FROM TABLE1 AS A
JOIN TABLE2 AS B ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

Comment: Ok. So What is the problem?

Comment: above code is dosent work.. any other solution for this condition...

Comment: @RajvardhanBabar What error you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "doesnt work"? Is there any exception you are getting?

Comment: this code i wrote in after insert trigger

Comment: i think its not working because of multiple columns in set statement ...Queery not give any exception as well as its not work